# SSRS Server Security Issue - where to ask?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

I have an issue with SSRS (MS SQL Server Reporting Services), that appears to be connected with security on the SSRS host box itself.  Without explaining the whole detail here, it appears that certain users need server-level permissions created or elevated before certain screens will render correctly, and I cannot understand why.

I cannot find a pre-existing answer, and am torn between posting on:

- Server Fault (but it's not really a Server Issue)
- Database Administrators (but it's not really a Database or BI issue - it's SSRS and/or server Security. Not MSSQL/SSRS usage)
- Stack Overflow (it's an issue with software, but not a coding issue; but also I'm likely to get an answer here)
- Super User (it's not really a user issue).
- Other?

There have seen suggestions to go with a "best fit" and let mods migrate if it's wrong, but I've also seen that approach attract a lot of downvotes for the poster.

Comment: It's not an SO question. SF and DBA both have an `ssrs` tag with a similar number of questions in each. You could take a look through [SF's questions](http://serverfault.com/questions/tagged/ssrs) and [DBA's questions](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ssrs) with that tag and see which one looks like the best bet. At a glance DBA's questions seem to be focused more on the underlying database while SF focuses on administrative tasks. Some sites have some overlap and this is OK The user bases of those sites are probably more equipped to answer your question than SU.

Comment: @Jason C, thanks.  TBH I was already sure it wasn't going to be SO, which is very frustrating (not for the first time) because I would probably get the fastest and best answer there.  My searches and tag analysis for issues in the approximate ballpark of mine showed a SO:SF:DBA:SU ratio of roughly 250:20:15:5, so I'll try SF.  (If you want to add your comments as the answer, I'm happy to accept)

Comment: By the way the suggestion to go with "best fit" is a good one. I wouldn't worry about downvotes. Well written questions tend to be more well received even if they need to be moved, and you've also shown good effort by asking here on meta first. Most of the downvoted cases you run into are generally where a person clearly did not care to put effort into figuring out what was on-topic on the site; SE users in general expect new users to read the basic rules. In any case, even if you end up getting downvotes, they don't really mean all that much, they're just downvotes.

Comment: @Jason C,  Unless you don't "do" the gamification thing, in which case every rep point is precious.  But that's another issue altogether....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say Server Fault. This appears to be the best fit.

As you say it's not a DBA issue as it appears to be about permissions on the box it's running on.

Server Fault is about running servers in professional environment and that includes the software that runs on these servers.